# Passing a regex expression to 'BeautifulSoup.find_all' doesn't work

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I pass multiple class values to `BeautifulSoup.find_all()`. The value is something like `l4 center` **OR** `l5 center`. (i.e., `"l4 center" | "l5 center"`).

```
soup.find_all("ul", {"class" :  value)
```

I fail (output nothing) to do that with the following two solution:

```
soup.find_all("ul", {"class" :  re.compile("l[4-5]\scenter")})

#OR

soup.find_all("ul", {"class" :  ["l4 center", "l5 center"]})
```

---

The source code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4
import requests
import requests.exceptions
import re

### function, , .... ###
def crawler_chinese_idiom():
    url = 'http://chengyu.911cha.com/zishu_8.html'
    response = requests.get(url)    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

    #for result_set in soup.find_all("ul", class=re.compile("l[45] +center")): #l4 center or l5 center
    for result_set in soup.find_all("ul", {"class", re.compile(r"l[45]\s+center")}): #nothing output
    #for result_set in soup.find_all("ul", {"class" :  "l4 center"}):  #normal one
        print(result_set)


crawler_chinese_idiom()
#[] output nothing
```

Comment: Try `re.compile(r"l[45]\s+center")`. Without `r`, you need to use ``\\s``, and `[45]` already mean 4 or 5.

Comment: what do you mean by  *It doesn't work*?

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: @stribizhev it doesn't work. Output nothing.

Comment: You have some other issue or your data is not what you say, it works fine. It would be alot easier if you provided the link/text of the data your parsing.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your HTML to test against.

Comment: Well shit. Seriously, that looks like a bug in Soup. This works: `soup.findAll('div', 'l4 center')`, but this does not: `soup.findAll('div', re.compile(r'l4 center'))`

Comment: @remus Report this bug to BeautifulSoup? Are there alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: resolved https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1476868

---

At first I thought the problem was that `class='l4 center'` in HTML is actually *two* classes -- thinking that soup won't match because it's looking for a single class that contains a space (impossible).

Tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><div class='l5 center'>l5test</div><div class='l4 center'>l4test</div><div class='l6 center'>l6test</div>")

results1 = soup.findAll('div', re.compile(r'l4 center'));
print results1
results2 = soup.findAll('div', 'l4 center');
print results2
```

Output:

```
[]
[<div class="l4 center">l4test</div>]
```

But wait? The non-regex option worked fine - it found both classes.

At this point, it looks to me like a BeautifulSoup bug.

To work around it, you could do:

```
soup.findAll('div', ['l4 center', 'l5 center']);
# update: ^ that doesn't work either.
# or
soup.findAll('div', ['l4', 'l5', 'center']);
```

I'd recommend the second one just in case you want to match `l4 otherclass center`, but you might need to iterate the results to make sure you don't have any unwanted captures in there. Something like:

```
for result in soup.findAll(...):
    if (result.find({'class': 'l4'}) and result.find({'class': 'center'}):
         # yay!
```

I've submitted a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1476868) for investigation.

Comment: `soup.findAll('div', ['l4 center', 'l5 center']);` doesn't work. Nothing output as well.

Comment: It works for me. `soup.findAll('div', ['l4', 'l5', 'center']);`

Comment: Submitted a bug report. For now you're probably stuck with that.